# Google Analytics in Web Application

Tags: google-analytics

Is it a good idea to put GA code in all pages of a web application? The web application have pages that can be accessed only by logged in users. Should I put GA code in the restricted pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should not put any analytical code in to restricted page and make them open to robots and crawlers.. May not be any security risk now but who knows some new threat might come and your restricted page becomes vulnerable.

By the way, in my blog I am using http://icrunched.co/all-in-one-webmaster/ for integrating the GA code in all pages as there not much user restricted content for it.

Comment: I once encountered a system that had delete links on their administrative pages, and these delete links expected the user to be authenticated previously (no check). And Google decided to crawl it. Bye bye, database!